# Resizable GameObject in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to unity.
Just want some help.
Can any body have any idea...Related to resizing the Gameobject by touch event for android device.
Actually i want to re-size the object on multi touch with my finger.
like we used zoom in & Zoom out in our mobiles.
Suppose i have a cube shape object. So i can rescale it dynamically on touch event.

Thanks

Comment: If you'd like an out-of-the-box solution, check out the Finger Gestures and EasyTouch gesture libraries in the Unity App Store.

Comment: I use FingerGestures in all my Unity3D project, especially for dealing with multiple targets like mobile and desktop. For example pinch maps to mouse wheel scrolling on the desktop automatically. Brilliant library.

Comment: @JeromeMaurey-Delaunay -- agreed. I use Finger Gestures also. Great library with great support from the author.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to determine how much user resize using multi touch

```
if (Input.touchCount >= 2)
{
    Vector2 touch0, touch1;
    float distance;
    touch0 = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
    touch1 = Input.GetTouch(1).position;

    distance = Vector2.Distance(touch0, touch1);
}
```

here is another script http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/301951/how-can-i-make-a-gameobject-scaleresize-with-mouse.html. use the distance from here in to that script. Looks like you're asking for whole script you just have to combine codes from above and make it work together.